# Macro to Paste Range Names

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

So far I have this.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("E3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CGSF.COMUTIL.2", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Sheet2!R3C5"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("CGSF.COMUTIL.2").Comment = ""
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CGSF.DISTRATE.2", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Sheet2!R3C6"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("CGSF.DISTRATE.2").Comment = ""
    Range("G3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CGSF.CC.2", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet2!R3C7"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("CGSF.CC.2").Comment = ""
    Range("H3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CGSF.FUNCTION.2", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Sheet2!R3C8"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("CGSF.FUNCTION.2").Comment = ""
End Sub
```

What I would like is to be able to provide a start column and an end column and then have the macro take the cell name and make it the range name for that cell.

Also is there a way to have add name:="" pull from the cell value instead of having to spell it out?

Comment: Do you want to recreate the named ranges in another workbook or just print the names in another workbook or both?

Comment: *Is it possible to put together a macro to take a list of names from one excel book and use those names to make range names in another workbook in a row consecutively.*  **YES**. Now, what is your *actual* question or problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have cell values in `Sheet2` from `E3 to H3` cells that needed to be converted into `Named Ranges`

```
Sub CellValue_To_NamedRange()
Dim a As Range, MyName As Range

Set a = Sheets(2).Range("E3:H3")

For Each MyName In a
 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=MyName, RefersTo:=MyName
Next

End Sub
```

Also, [From Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835300(v=office.15).aspx) there is not way to add comments to named ranges through vba